# How to implement .Join()?

Tags: linq-to-sql, join

Can anyone help me learn how to implement .Join()? I've never used .Join() before (only the regular 'join') and would like to learn how to. Thanks!

```
    IQueryable<MyClass> query = 
      from t in table
      select new MyClass() { t.id, t.name };

   IQueryable<MyClass2> ids = 
      from t2 in table2
      select t2.id; // integers

    query.Join(ids, ___, ___, ___)
```

This wouldn't work...

```
query.Join(ids, o => o.id, p => p, (o, p) => (o.id == p));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. It looks like you're expecting the last parameter to `Join` to be the join criteria. That's incorrect (the `Join` method assumes equals).

The last parameter is selecting the result of the join:

```
var result = query.Join(ids, q => q.id, i => i, (q, i) => new { q , i });
```

The MSDN Page for `Enumerable.Join()` actually has a really good example at the bottom of the page. I would suggest checking it out to better understand what is going on:

[MSDN - Enumerable.Join() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work, but it's doing a left outer join. Do you know if there's a way to make it perform an inner join? I want it to return only the records from 'query' that successfully join on 'ids'. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @GoatBreeder - Join performs an the equivalent to an inner join. I'm guessing there's more code that you have't posted...or I am misunderstanding your data.